# Why is :execute required in this --remote-silent command?

Tags: cursor-motions, clientserver

Let's say I want to jump to a particular position in a file in an existing Vim server:

This command jumps to the correct line, but *not* the correct column, leaving the cursor at the start of the line:

```
gvim.exe --servername VimServer --remote-silent +"normal! 5G5|"
```

If I add in an `:execute`, however, the command works as desired:

```
gvim.exe --servername VimServer --remote-silent +"execute 'normal! 5G5|'"
```

Note that removing the `5G` line movement does not affect the issue. `normal! 5|` jumps to the start of the current line. `execute 'normal! 5|'` jumps to the fifth column.

I also tried a few other motions. These will all leave the cursor at the start of the (correct) line unless run with `:execute`:

```
normal! w
normal! l
normal! j
normal! )
normal! %
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked deeply into it, but reading [`:help --remote`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/remote.txt.html#--remote), it mentions this about `+{cmd}`:

> This must be an Ex command that can be followed by "|".

Your `:normal` interprets the remainder as normal mode commands; you'd need a `:{cmd}` to execute `{cmd}` as an Ex command. By wrapping this in `:execute`, only the quoted string is executed, and the normal mode initiated by `:normal` ends after that, and additional Ex commands can follow after a `|`, as requested.